# Error when duplicating Joomla setup

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla installation set up on my local server. I have duplicated with a new name the top-level Joomla folder so that all the information I have already put into the database can be edited slightly, whilst still keeping the original intact.

I have copied the database files over to a new database and made the relevant changes in Joomla admin. I've opened up configuration.php and changed all the file paths to the new one.

However, now I'm getting a server error when trying to access the web page and admin area. Are there any other files I need to edit with the new path to enable it to work under the new parent folder?

Comment: Did you check your .htaccess ? Did you check the server logs ? More information could be useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to edit any files with any paths to make it work other than the tmp and log folders and the root folder line in htaccess if you have SEF URLs turned on. Turn off SEF URLs and see if the site starts working, if it does, then you need to edit htaccess. Since your admin is not working, my guess is that you messed up your configuration.php. Copy over the original unedited version to the copy site, it should work. You can then adjust the tmp and log paths within the admin in the global configuration.